# Schengen visa for Filipino same-sex fiance of a UK citizen living in Italy

Tags: united-kingdom, france, spain, italy, philippine-citizens

I am a UK citizen. I wish to live in Italy, France or Spain and wish to enter into a same-sex civil union with my Filipino boyfriend, who is in the Philippines and has an aunt living legally in France. Can someone advise me what our best option is.

Comment: One you're in a registered partnership or marriage together, you can move to any of those three countries together with minimal formalities, thanks to EU freedom of movement.  If you do that, however, it's not clear what your rights would be after the UK leaves the EU.

Comment: i understand. but not possible  to register same sex union in Philippines. So first he needs schengen visa

Comment: Have you been together for a long time? If so, he might be able to qualify for freedom of movement as "the partner with whom you have a durable relationship."  If not, you're right, you'll need to find a jurisdiction where you can register your partnership.

Comment: I should have noted in my long-ago comment that you can marry in the US, if you want to do that.  I believe some states would also register your partnership.  There are surely other jurisdictions that allow nonresidents to marry or register partnerships.